# How to disable IPv6 permanently?

Tags: networking, security, ipv6

How can we disable IPv6 system wide via terminal commands?

I've read editing **/etc/modprobe.d/aliases** 
and replacing:

```
alias net-pf-10 ipv6
```

with:

```
alias net-pf-10 off
alias ipv6 off
```

Is this safe to apply and does it permanently disable ipv6 across reboots?

Comment: Why do you want to disable IPv6 permanently?

Comment: There are absolutly (well, I can actually find one, on MS Windows) no reason to turn IPv6 off.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Some Wi-Fi spots are very slow at IPv6, unfortunately.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 doesn't make you immune to IPv6 attacks. It is much better to have it enabled, deal with it and learn from it, that is the only way make your environment a bit safier. It is better for everybody to learn "How to to disable IPv4 permanently", instead.

IPv6 is far much easier than IPv4, to begin with, there no NAT anymore, so, one less thing to manage... The Internet is growing really fast, in a few years, the IPv6 network will be bigger than IPv4, so, with IPv4, you'll be out of the real Internet. Go ahead man! Upgrade your IP!! Change is a good thing.

Comment: BTW, take a look at the "RFC 7123", it is about "Security Implications of IPv6 on IPv4 Networks", cheers!

Comment: @AndersonGreen I need to do this. Bug Workaround, wireless won't connect in newer Ubuntu versions with it enabled, works fine when disabled

Comment: @cmc Exactly! So true.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher and others - These comments are no helpful. Just because you may not be aware of a reason to disable IPv6, doesn't mean there isn't one. One major case is for VPN services that don't support IPv6. If you don't disable it, you will leak your IPv6 address.

Comment: I disagree... the safest thing to do is to disable it on your systems, and drop the packets at your routers. From a person managing a network, I have better things to worry about. I'll revisit the situation in 10 years, if it manages to ever take off.

Comment: I work in the IoT world. IPv6 is a pain in my ass. I turn it off always. Slows things down, slows boot time, at times you end up with multiple IP's per device which creates issues in some networks, cause for security concern, need to document IPv6 in technical documentation if you end up using it, and there really is no advantage to IPv6 at this time, etc.  I can turn it on on a use-case basis if needed.

Comment: see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190189

Comment: I turned it off because apt get was failing while trying to use ipv6, due to timeouts.  ipv4 worked just fine.

Comment: Another reason to turn it off is to work around bugs. My product once used some third-party code that had bugs in the case of IPv6 addresses and we didn't have access to the source code at that time so we couldn't fix them by ourselves. Meanwhile, we needed to deliver the product to our customers so at that time the best thing was to disable IPv6. We re-enabled IPv6 after we fixed the bugs in the third-party code eventually.

Answer (score 91):

I successfully disabled IPv6 once putting the following lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

also run this command to load changes

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Uubuntu on VMware can't be ping, and I close the ipv6 on Ubuntu, it is ok now.

Comment: After these adding lines to sysctl.conf, run `sudo sysctl -p` or reboot to let changes take effect.

Comment: I need to do this only on wireless as a bug workaround so I can connect again. Here's how to do it for one adapter only: `net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.disable_ipv6 = 1`

Comment: This didn't work for me on UbuntuMate 16.10. I had to specific the Wifi interface specifically, similar to how @cmc suggests above.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 17.10. See NullNoname comment below for the grub fix.

Comment: I just did this on my Kubuntu 17.10 install. Added the lines mentioned in parent comment, then ran `sudo sysctl -p` and voila, I'm no longer leaking on any of the tests I've run [test-ipv6](http://test-ipv6.com/), [whatsmyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), [ipleak](https://www.ipleak.net/)

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 as well. Grub method works.

Comment: bash: net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6: command not found

Comment: @hellomoto That's not a command. You have to put those lines in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: This solved a problem I suddenly began experiencing with Linux Mint 18.3 32-bit update manager and updating apt repositories. But it annoys / worries me that this became necessary. Wish I understood why formerly working apt / apt-get / update manager suddenly had problems accessing repos...

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 for the current session, but I haven't rebooted my system since to see if it would survive the reboot.

Comment: I use a vpn and this command doesn't help switch to ipv4, while my android phone use the same vpn and can get ipv4 and hidden location.

Comment: this fix, on 22.04 LTS, does not persist on my VMs on vSphere.  How do I run sysctl -p at boot?

Answer (score 72):

If your PC doesn't load /etc/sysctl.conf at boot time (which is the case for me), disabling IPv6 from grub is needed. Linux kernel has a boot option named "ipv6.disable=1" which disables IPv6 from startup.

To edit the boot options, edit "/etc/default/grub" with any text editor as root user:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that contain "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT":

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add "ipv6.disable=1" to the boot option, then save your grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

Finally, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: +1 this works and disables IPv6 completely, so there are no traces of `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/` left which may produce problems like `X11 forwarding request failed` because `sshd` tries to bind to a non-configured IPv6 interface.  Note that similarly you can get rid of IPv4 this way on pure IPv6 VMs.  Thanks.

Comment: This works for me on 20.10. A cleaner way is to create a file `/etc/default/grub.d/disable-ipv6.cfg` with the contents `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} ipv6.disable=1"`. Don't forget `update-grub`.

Comment: @Tino did a find a solution to the sshd problem?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand There might be, but I tried nothing else, as disabling IPv6 at boot time fixes it for me.

Comment: @schieferstapel on ubuntu 18.04 now my system wont boot anymore after creating your file

Comment: Ubuntu 20 VM: This was the only functional way for me. sysctl.conf didn't help.

Comment: This should be the first answer as this is the only way I have found after hours that guarantee ipv6 will be disabled.

Answer (score 10):

Carvalho's answer including the comment about having to run `sudo sysctl -p` has helped me the most.

However, in my case at least:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.<mydevice>.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and it seems the second line was necessary.

Maybe this has to do with the fact that I am using the TP-Link Archer T2U, for which I had to customly build a driver from source.

My assumption is that as a result, `<mydevice>` doesn't count as one of "`all`".

So, in a nutshell, if you have customly added a (custom) networking driver, `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` might not be sufficient to disable IPv6 networking.

Have to admit though, that I didn't try the line `net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1`.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning that disabling different devices is sometimes required.

Comment: The lack of the `default` line is probably the problem here. If your driver wasn't loaded yet at the point in the boot process when the sysctl was executed, then it wasn't included in `all` -- but setting the default would have meant it would have gotten the setting later, when it *was* loaded.

Comment: I had the `default` entry and I had to configure the specific device to successfully disable it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to check to see if ipv6 is enabled on your computer

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"
```

If you see

```
Running kernel is IPv6 ready
```

it is enabled.

If you see no output, it is not.

To disable ipv6 if the other answers on this page don't work for you, blacklist ipv6 all-together. To do this, use the following command:

```
echo 'blacklist ipv6' | sudo tee -a '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local' >/dev/null
```

Also, this might help as well:

```
echo 'install ipv6 /bin/true' | sudo tee -a '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local' >/dev/null
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect. To check if it's enabled after startup run this command again:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"
```

There should be no output.

[Click here for info on how to disable IPV6 at boot.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190189)

Comment: This answer assumes that the kernels `ipv6` feature is a kernel module (using `blacklist.local` to prevent its loading). There is a case that ipv6 is compiled into the kernel (not a module) in which case it is necessary to boot the kernel with `ipv6.disable=1` boot paremeter (to do so one would: (1) `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` (2) search for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=<args>` and (3) add `ipv6.disable=1` to the boot parameters )

Comment: @humanityANDpeace You may be interested in this more comprehensive answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190189

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a modern version (I'm on 16.04 LTS) of Ubuntu then you can use this tidy solution:

Create `/etc/sysctl.d/60-ipv6-disable.conf` containing the following text:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run `service procps start`

Comment: this is the cleanest way to do it - don't understand why was downvoted.
it works on fedora/centos/redhat, too.
it has the advantage that it does not alter system defaults files (like directly sysctl.conf as suggested in most popular answer)

Comment: @Costin I didn't downvote, but this won't always work. Sometimes you have to put the specific device name (e.g. in case of custom driver installations). See Alfonso Nishikawas comment on my answer.

Comment: I'm thankful I followed this approach, because I ended up losing my connection on a remote server (it *needed* IPv6), and it was very easy to direct my assistant on site to remove the one file and reboot.

Comment: i had to run `service procps restart` instead on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Putting it in `sysctl.d` doesn't persist through reboots, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

On a raspberry pi running Ubuntu, prepend

```
ipv6.disable=1
```

to

```
/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
```

to disable IPv6 at the kernel level.