# Wifi connetion does not start at boot at ubuntu 13.04 server

Tags: 13.04, boot, wireless, networking

I have an ubuntu 13.04 server and want to connect to my network via wifi. At boot I get "Waiting for network configuration..." and "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...". However my wifi LED is not turned on and get no connection.

When I run

```
sudo service networking restart
```

the wifi LED is turned on and I connect quickly.

This is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid MySSID
    wpa-psk  MyPassword
```

Do you have any idea how to connect immediately at boot?

Edit:

[My dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/KTeaWVPZ)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it added to the boot-up routine with the following:

```
sudo update-rc.d networking defaults
```

If that doesn't work or if it tells you it's already there, make sure it isn't crashing at bootup.  This will show you error messages in the log:

```
dmesg | tail 40
```

You can find [more helpful information about starting services at boot-up time here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I added my dmesg output to the original question, but could not detect anything promising. Maybe in line 749: "wlan0: link is not ready"?

Comment: Based on your `dmesg` I wonder if your networking service is starting too soon.  Try changing the order so it starts last (this is old but may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/193115/how-can-i-change-the-service-boot-order-in-ubuntu-server-10-04).  You may also try disabling IPv6 since that is what it complained about:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently

Comment: Thanks, but still no success. http:://pastebin.com/x0yxpnNv - dmesg

Comment: Wow I'm running out of ideas :-O  Try running `sudo service networking restart` as an upstart task and see if that does it  http://askubuntu.com/a/1135/136192 .  In the script you probably want the first line `#!/bin/bash` and the second line `sudo service networking restart`

Comment: I've now installed ubuntu 12.04 and everything works well. The LTS version seems to be much more stable. Thank you very much for helping anyway.