# My boot time has significantly increased

Tags: boot, 16.04, performance

Fairly new to Ubuntu so please help me as best as you can. I'm a tad confused on what to do from here so if there's more info that's needed let me know.

[dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/kE1dHMXj)

systemd-analyze blame:

```
5.190s udev-configure-printer@-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb3-3\
           764ms mnt-Programs\x2dGames.mount
           676ms dev-sdb5.device
           617ms mnt-Data.mount
           335ms plymouth-start.service
           304ms networking.service
           269ms plymouth-read-write.service
           ...
```

I should point out I did get rid of the swap space and moved it elsewhere so I'm sure that's likely related since if I remember correctly that's around when things slowed down.

Comment: What did you exactly do to move the swap space? A look at `~/.bash_history` might help to remember.

Comment: When you look at the dmesg you see a jump in time here: "[ 97.278032] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready" 
So start by disabling IPv6 on your network and see if that was the issue.

Comment: I moved the Swap space by deleting the partition and making a new one on a different drive.

Comment: and `systemd-analyze blame` will show the services in order of slowest. add the results to the question ;) @chili555 this might be one for you (looks like a wireless problem).

Comment: If I did it correctly which I doubt I did, disabling IPv6 didn't change anything. How would I go about disabling it, just to be sure I did it correctly?

Comment: ipv6: http://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite tired. Could you give me a step by step on what to do here? I can't seem to get myself to look through that and actually figure out what to do.

Comment: If what you need help with, is disabling the IPv6, run this `sudo echo -e net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 \\nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 \\nnet.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf ` and reboot.

Comment: (forgive me as I don't understand how the formating thing works to make it look nicer.) Using that command @M.Becerra didn't change my boot time much. However it did come up with : tee: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `echo -e net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 \\nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 \\nnet.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf` .  Permission denied means you need root privileges to edit that file. With`sudo`, you run the command as the root.

Comment: @M.Becerra I tried it again, and no improvements. The first jump in time in dmesg still refers to IPv6 though.

Comment: I guess I'll look elsewhere for answers. Thanks anyways.