# Why my options in the files in sysctl.d are not permanent? I need to run `sudo sysctl -p` often

Tags: networking, kernel, ipv6

Following some tutorials to disable ipv6 in my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04), I needed to write in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` the following lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I run `sudo sysctl -p` and ipv6 is disabled. Fine.

After some time, or if I restart *NetworkManager*, or reboot my computer, I find in *ifconfig* that my ipv6 address got back, and I have to run `sudo sysctl -p` again.

So I cannot understand why my configuration is not definitive and **something ignores my kernel parameters at runtime**.

Comment: After creating 99-sysctl.conf, did you `sudo service procps start`?

Comment: @CharlesGreen will putting it in the sysctl.conf make a difference?

Comment: @George I don't remember if I did it on purpose but  `sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` and `sysctl.conf` are identical. So there is no difference.

Comment: @CharlesGreen if I do `sudo service procps status` I can see that is already active, moreover I can restart it and it fix ipv6 temporarily, until NetworkManager is restarted, then it gets back its ipv6.

Comment: Why would you create `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`, if it is identical to `/etc/sysctl.conf`?  The reason for my suggestion of `procps` can be found in `/etc/sysctl.d/README`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes i eliminated one of the two (first one then the other) and I  run sudo service procps start, but the behavior remains. The parameters  don't look  permanent.

Comment: There is an alternate method for disabling ipv6 which worked well for me when I was having some problems  [https://askubuntu.com/a/337736/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/337736/283721)

Comment: Also, there is an older bug report which I assume would have been fixed by now, and which may be applicable to your system [https://serverfault.com/a/494899](https://serverfault.com/a/494899)

Comment: @DdD on my Debian, sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf is symlinked to sysctl.conf.

Answer (score 4):

There is a reported problem affecting up to Ubuntu 16.04, at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093 in which procps.sh which applies the sysctl.conf variable is run too early, and some settings are not applied.

An alternate method for disabling ipv6 is to use a kernel boot parameter as outlines in https://askubuntu.com/a/337736/283721

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that contain "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT":

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add "ipv6.disable=1" to the boot option, then save your grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano. Finally, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot to load the changes.