# eduroam randomly drops connection

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant, dhclient

As the title says, when on eduroam my internet connection drops after some time (usually after a couple of minutes when I have a lot of traffic, e.g. zoom meetings, when there is less traffic it might hold for an hour). The laptop stays connected to the wifi but no website is accessible and I also can't ping any DNS servers (though existing connections with e.g. Netflix sometimes still work). I don't have this issue on Windows.

The journalctl output while when this happens is

```
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with f0:9e:63:05:60:71 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: disconnect from AP 34:6f:90:34:24:8e for new auth to f0:9e:63:05:60:71
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticate with f0:9e:63:05:60:71
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.1322] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.1323] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: send auth to f0:9e:63:05:60:71 (try 1/3)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: Trying to associate with f0:9e:63:05:60:71 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.1582] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.1582] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: associate with f0:9e:63:05:60:71 (try 1/3)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: RX ReassocResp from f0:9e:63:05:60:71 (capab=0x421 status=17 aid=0)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: f0:9e:63:05:60:71 denied association (code=17)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=f0:9e:63:05:60:71 status_code=17
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.2197] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.2198] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.3201] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.3202] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (SSID='eduroam' freq=5240 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: send auth to 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (try 1/3)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.4885] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.4886] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (SSID='eduroam' freq=5240 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.5025] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111619.5025] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: associate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (try 1/3)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (capab=0x101 status=30 aid=0)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: 34:6f:90:34:24:8e rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 1000 TU (1024 ms)
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:19 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: Connection to AP 34:6f:90:34:24:8e lost
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: associate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (try 2/3)
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (capab=0x101 status=30 aid=0)
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: 34:6f:90:34:24:8e rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 1000 TU (1024 ms)
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:20 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: Connection to AP 34:6f:90:34:24:8e lost
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: associate with 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (try 3/3)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 34:6f:90:34:24:8e (capab=0x1101 status=17 aid=0)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: 34:6f:90:34:24:8e denied association (code=17)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=34:6f:90:34:24:8e status_code=17
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.6374] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.6374] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.7377] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.7378] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 34:6f:90:34:24:81 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.8833] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 34:6f:90:34:24:81
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: send auth to 34:6f:90:34:24:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.8834] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux wpa_supplicant[1062]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 34:6f:90:34:24:81 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux NetworkManager[1239]: <info>  [1599111621.9074] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 02 22:40:21 carlos-linux kernel: wlo1: authenticated
```

This is the same issue as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230963&p=2), but the fix there does not work for me. I guess that's because my Ubuntu networking config is different from their Arch config, so if anyone can tell me what to change in my config to make it match Arch's ("default") config, I would also appreciate that.

**Edit:** The problem is caused by switching APs so fixing the BSSID for the network in Gnome's config fixes the disconnects, but this probably not optimal...

**Edit 2:** It seems that my wifi adapter is being recognized as `Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)` even though it's a intel AX201. I also found these lines in my dmesg:

```
[    4.382504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.387696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.387716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
```

Does this mean that the wrong firmware is being loaded for the device?

**Diagnostics:**

- When this happens `mtr` says "no route to host"
- `pgrep -a dh` gives two entries:

```
995171 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlo1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-85e18157-cc78-4948-a5fb-300853e6bb8b-wlo1.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlo1.conf wlo1

995228 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -6 -S -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/NetworkManager/dhclient6-wlo1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-85e18157-cc78-4948-a5fb-300853e6bb8b-wlo1.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-wlo1.conf wlo1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not violating Eduroam TOS using Netflix? You can't even `mtr 1.1.1.1`? What's the output of `ss -tpn` and `pgrep -a dh`? Does restarting solve the problem?

Comment: @PabloBianchi Eduroam is provided as wifi where I live and I'm pretty sure they don't mind me using Netflix. The problem happens when I don't have a lot of traffic too. I posted the output to some of those commands. The output of `ss -tpn` is rather long, is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: @PabloBianchi Restarting of course fixes the problem (as does reconnecting to the network) but the connection typically drops again after a few minutes.

Comment: [This case](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1751610#p1751610) is related to having dhcpcd.service enabled, which doesn't seem the case. I would check [disabling IPv6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently?answertab=active#comment1362028_309461) and checking `journalctl -k -p err` before/after the network goes down

Comment: Buy a good WLAN-stick: https://skinflint.co.uk/?cat=nwpcie&xf=14067_USB-A+3.0~14072_WLAN+802ac11~14073_400~14074_867&hloc=eu
;
For example https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-AC68/ is one on the high end and has imho good linux-driver-support.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the IT support for where you live to confirm whether or not they are blocking you because of Netflix?  You probably want to be more sure than "pretty sure" before investing time on troubleshooting this.  I Googled a bit and it does seem like some campuses do block Netflix access...  Is there a Windows/Mac user you know who accesses the same sites you are who also have no network connection problems?

Comment: @Ray 1. I can use Netflix on Windows without any problems. 2. The problem also happens when I'm not using Netflix (not even using any website) and stays when I change my mac address. 3. The problem is caused by my network card deciding to switch APs but this is not caused by the AP since it doesn't happen when I fix the AP.

Comment: I see.  What version of Ubuntu is this?  If all else fails and you really want to try anything to fix this problem, you can consider upgrading your version of Ubuntu (that is, if it isn't 20.10).  I've had similar problems before and only after upgrading did it solve my problems.  Sure, there was probably a bigger underlying problem associated with the settings, etc. but upgrading solved it for me at that time.

Comment: I'm using 20.10 but the problem already happened on 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution online that seems to have worked, at least for me:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230963&p=2

I followed **nstarclix**'s procedure and removed some steps which were not possible in Ubuntu. Here's what worked for me:

First, modify the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and add the following lines:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

(Also, make sure you have dhclient installed, I believe it's an Ubuntu default)

Then check the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, you should have the name server set to `127.0.0.53`, it seems to be the default

Then the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service
```

Now reboot and hopefully everything will work, although I haven't tried this solution for a long period of time just yet.

Comment: My spanking brand new Ubuntu 20.04 with a D-link DWA-582 wifi card dropped several times a day and had pretty bad performance in general. Changing to dhclient and not a single drop the last two days...

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the necrobump. After trawling and trying various things for
the hp elitebook 640 g9 on ubuntu, the fix looks to have been updating the BIOS.

(eduroam kept dropping issue)