The correct way to get resolved working and disable ipv6
I'm running Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS and having issues doing things the "correct" ubuntu way.
First, I'm trying to get systemd-resolved to work:

I specifically want to use systemd-resolved and to keep caching. I also want to continue to run in stub mode.
If at all possible, I want to avoid un-symlinking or modifying existing files. I would rather add drop-in configs where possible.
The nameservers I specified via netplan appear in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, but /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf is what's symlinked at /etc/resolv.conf.
resolvectl query google.com works as expected and caches responses.
host google.com does not work and returns communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out.
systemctl status systemd-resolved shows the service running with a status of "processing requests".
lsof -i :53 shows systemd-resolve at 127.0.0.53 and 127.0.0.54 tcp + udp, but only the TCP entries have "(LISTEN)" next to them.

Second, I'm trying to disable ipv6 altogether:

I have set several values in /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf but this doesn't seem to be impacting anything after a reboot.
networkctl status shows my network in a routable state but a partial online state.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I feel like this is the hardest I've ever had to fight a linux install.
/etc/netplan/99-ip.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.137/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [9.9.9.11,149.112.112.11]

/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.disable_ipv6=1


Related? https://askubuntu.com/a/1444707/158442

That would take care of a single known interface, but I'd prefer to just have ipv6 off everywhere.

Sure, but that answer says that systemd-networkd will re-enable IPv6 even if it is disabled via sysconf settings if it thinks IPv6 can be used for a device, even if only for zeroconf. So try disabling link-local network config in systemd-netwrokd.

Creating this and restarting systemd-networkd gets rid of link local addresses but doesn't disable ipv6 totally. Probably fine for my purposes.
/etc/systemd/network/99-no-ipv6-linklocal.network
[Match]
Type=*

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=No


Nice, you can post that as an answer

Related, I've just filed https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/35415 because systemd-resolved doesn't seem to apply the no-aaaa option when set in NetworkManager. I'm not adding this as an answer as it's unclear what exactly you want to disable IPv6 for.
